# Cases with backward air flow?

Tags: computer-building, case

I would like find other cases that have backward air flow like the [LIAN LI PC-A05](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811112218).

I will be putting this box in a place where the household A/C is blowing from the back of the case to the front.  My current computer in this location overheats in the summer because it is working against prevailing winds.

Comment: Couldn't you just...turn the fans around?

Comment: I don't think Super User is supposed to be used in a way that other users can look up cases for you.

Comment: @rschuler: I'm not sure that this question is formatted in the right way.  Perhaps you might want to re-word it to make it a better question.  I also agree with Jonathon Sampson

Comment: I think you mean cases with positive pressure, as apposed to normal cases that are negative pressure.

Answer (score 7):

Dude, just flip the fans around in the case.

Comment: Easier said than done on the power supply fan.  Some power supplies are welded shut.  If you can open it those big capacitors inside can knock you for a loop if you are not careful when flipping the fan inside the power supply.

Comment: Yes, for the power supply fan you're exactly right.  But in that event, you'd be looking for an inverted fan on the power supply - not on the case.

Answer (score 4):

Unless your air conditioner is blowing at 100 kph, it has no effect on the flow of air inside the case.  This is not the reason your system is overheating.

EDIT: rather than buying a new case, you are probably better off buying an additional case fan, or a bigger one.  Cheaper and more likely to work.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn your whole desk around. Or move the case to somewhere with better airflow.